# Read Timed Out uploading to Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

In my Android app, I have to upload files to Google Drive.  Up until yesterday I have had 0 problems with the upload.  It has been working fine for over a year.  All of a sudden now I am getting a lot of failed uploads.  Most of the time I get a "Read Timed Out" but occasionally i will get java.io.eofexception.  Some of the uploads are just delayed, maybe 20 seconds for a small file instead of the normal 2 seconds, but mostly they fail.  The uploads happen one right after the other and 1 or 2 out of every 10 uploads have this problem.

I tried with the latest 1.15.0-rc libraries, also with some older libraries, and also with the latest google-api-services-drive-v2-rev82-1.14.2-beta.jar library.  Nothing seems to help.

Is something going on with Google Drive?  I checked the status page and it doesn't show any problems.

I also created a new test project which removes all my code and I used new code to just upload 10 files in a row from the mediastore as a test and this app is also having the same problem.

EDIT:  I tested on 3 different networks and they all produced the same behavior.

Here is an example of the exception:

```
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758): exception thrown while executing request
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:664)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at libcore.io.Streams.readSingleByte(Streams.java:41)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:648)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:573)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:821)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:495)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:95)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:980)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:456)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:362)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:420)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
06-28 06:09:12.942: W/HttpTransport(5758):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
```

Comment: when network not able to connect with url then after some time it will throw timeout error

Comment: you have to catch that exception and return with some value

Comment: The network was ok.  I tested with wifi, 4g, and also my friend tested on his network with the same problem.  I did catch the exception, i pasted it into message.  That is the stacktrace.

Comment: can you coment you code here so i can check

Comment: Some times happens with zero length files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem went away around 30 hours later without any code changes.  It must have been a problem with Google Drive.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've encountered problems with Google Drive service on a regular basis. In 6 months, I have 14 incidents where the service has been down for more than an hour - every attempt fired every 10 minutes.

Comment: @Wrench right there with ya. Starting to wonder whether Google Drive is actually ready as a platform for developers...